# Importing Issues in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, api, import, pylance

In VS code, I am getting these Problems:

Import "flask" could not be resolved from source Pylance

it's this same problem for "googleapiclient.discovery, google_auth_oauthlib.flow, google.auth.transport.requests, and oauth2client.service_account.

At first I thought there was an issue with my pickle token or credentials file for the Google API, but those are working. I think. I then just made a blank new file, and just wrote

`import pandas as pd`

and I'm still getting the same error for that. I know I have pandas installed through pip. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: first, check the pip version and python version. maybe you have installed packages using python2's pip and you are importing it in python3's script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have selected a Python environment that has the packages installed. You can also add custom search paths if necessary but the environment selection is more likely your problem. You may find this blog post helpful: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-july-2021-release/